# How long to crack HMAC sha256 digest private key given data

Tags: javascript, sha256, hmac

We've built a javascript module which can be embedded in third-party webpages.  When this client module is initialized, it executes a transaction within our web application via a cross-site request.

The transaction consists of an external uuid, an email, and some additional meta properties. This message is signed with an HMAC sha256 digest, using our partner's private API key.

Ruby example:

```
data = {
  uuid: "ABCAFAFDS",
  email: "email@gmail.com",
  meta: {}
}

private_key = "Qd9fe0y2ezqfae4Qj6At"
signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(
  OpenSSL::Digest.new("sha256"),
  private_key,
  data.to_json
)
```

Within the third-party webpage, the javascript client is then initialized with the signature and the data:

`new Client(signature, data).execute()`;

Initially, our plan was to allow the client to create a partial / incomplete transaction within our system and then require a subsequent back-end request via our REST API to confirm / finalize the transaction. Assuming that we can secure the front-end, however, it would be preferential to remove the back-end confirmation requirement.

Can we reasonably secure the client code using signed messages in this fashion? If the data and the signed message is available in the client, how difficult would it be for a bad actor to brute force the API private key length, given the length above?

Comment: Probably better suited for http://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most internet traffic has signed tokens on the client these days.  All your gmail logins, facebook logins, etc do this so it is fairly standard.  I'd recommend using an existing standard (and 3rd party library) rather than roll your own token though.  This will let you leverage other people's expertise in this area.

JWT (json web token) is in common use and there are many libraries for working with JWT's.  See https://jwt.io for more information.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, using JWT versus rolling our own implementation is a great point.  Still one question, though.  In the JWT tutorials, the token is generated on the back-end and sent to the client.    The client does not see the unsigned payload or headers.  With our module, the payload information is effectively discernible in the UI (uuid, email, the meta properties, etc) since we are visually displaying these properties.  Does that break the security of the protocol?  Does it make it easier for hackers to guess the private key, given their knowledge of the payload and headers?

Comment: No it is essentially the same — jwt tokens are just signed, not encrypted. They look obfuscated only because the token is base64 encoded. You can use clientside jwt libraries to decode a token and get the contents for display purposes.  Note that jwt tokens support multiple signing algorithms—there are symmetric and asymmetric algorithms which means you can even use an asymmetric algorithm which will allow anyone (even the client) to use the public key to verify the authenticity of the token without having access to the private key.

Comment: And, obviously, since the tokens are not encrypted, don’t put any data into the token that should be kept secret from the client